# Using Django ModelForm with non-persistent model.Field

Tags: python, django

Is there a way to add a field to a Django model class such that:

1. It doesn't get persisted to the database (i.e. no column in the DB)
2. It does get rendered by a ModelForm
3. The widget for that field can be customised

I believe 3. can be done with a custom widget, and 2. will happen if the field inherits from `models.Field`. However, I haven't found a way to achieve 1. without breaking 2. and 3. I was hoping for a `persist=False` or `db_column=None` type of solution.

Scenario:

I'm using this to quickly produce data capture forms by only adding a class to the model, but in order to insert headers for sub sections I still having to edit the template. Was hoping to do the following:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

class Applicant(models.Model):    
    sectionA = models.SectionField(help_text="Personal details")
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    sectionB = models.SectionField(help_text="Banking details")
    account = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    pin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

In the above example, sectionA and sectionB are instances of a custom `model.Field` that doesn't actually get persisted but cause a heading to be rendered by the ModelForm and a custom widget

Finally:

- I realise this probably violates separation of View and Model.
- Other questions have been asked about non-persisting fields but their solutions don't render in a ModelForm

Answer (score 1):

Sort of, Just don't make them a model field, theres no need for them to be.

```
sectionA = "Personal details"
sectionB = "Banking details"
```

You can access them via `form.instance` where you need them, you could even make them a form field instead of a string as I've shown here.

Comment: Yes, this does violate the separation and I'm not terribly fond of this idea :)